# Proguardgui doesnt de-obfuscates stack traces.

Tags: proguard

I am trying de-obfuscating an android stack trace using proguardgui but De-obfuscated stack trace remains the same as the stack trace. I am not getting why am i facing the problem.
Please help.[image: using Proguardgui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, i have learnt that the stack trace need to be formatted properly. See the difference between upper and below stack trace. The only difference is formatting.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at b.e.b.b.a.a.<init>(SourceFile:55)
at com.morpho.c.e.<init>(SourceFile:38)
at com.bio.cip.LoginActivity_.onCreate(SourceFile:47)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.a.a.c.z.<clinit>(SourceFile:209)
    ... 17 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PUBLIC_ONLY
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:260)
at com.a.a.c.f.y.<clinit>(SourceFile:172)
    ... 18 more
 Failed to get ILowStorageHandle instance
```